# Confuse about activity launch

Tags: android

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getContext());
            builder.setAutoCancel(true);
            builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
            builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
            builder.setContentTitle("abc");
            builder.setContentText("abc");
            builder.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(getContext(), 0,
                    new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class).replaceExtras(bundle).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP),
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
            builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            manager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

first way to set launch mode.

```
<activity
        android:name=".activity.mainActivity.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" 
        android:launchMode="singleTask"/>
```

second way to set launch mode.

Google offical document.

```
FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
```

Start the `Activity` in a new task. If a task is already running for the activity you are now starting, that task is brought to the foreground with its last state restored and the activity receives the new intent in `onNewIntent()`.
This produces the same behavior as the "singleTask" launchMode value, discussed in the previous section.

activity stack a,b,`MainActivity`

Why `onNewIntent()` not invoked in first way.
Why activity(a,b) not cleaned in first way.

Answer (score 0):

1. by using `android:launchMode="singleTask"`
   "**singleTask**" and "**singleInstance**" activities can only begin a task. They are always at the root of the activity stack. Moreover, the device can hold only one instance of the activity at a time — only one such task.
2. by using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` It set, this activity will become the start of a new task on this history stack.

Comment: Activities using "singleTask" and "singleInstance" are not always at the root of activity stack.

Comment: your first point is wrong: "The system creates a new task and instantiates the activity at the root of the new task. However, if an instance of the activity already exists in a separate task, the system routes the intent to the existing instance"https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Comment: @WilliMentzel  I agree with you.